# How to convert RTF to Docx in Python

Tags: python, doxygen, docx, rtf

I'm using doxygen to generate rtf output, but I need the rtf converted to docx in an automated way using python to run on a build system.

- Input: example.rtf
- Output: example.docx

I don't want to change any of the styling, formatting, or content.  Just do a direct conversion.  The same way it would be done manually by opening the .rtf in word and then doing SaveAs .docx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent a lot of time and energy trying to figure this out, so I thought I would post the question and solution for the community.  It was actually very simple in the end, but took a long time to find the correct information to accomplish this.

This solution requires the following:

- Python 3.x
- PyWin32 module
- Windows 10 environment (haven't tried it with other flavors of Windows)

```
#convert rtf to docx and embed all pictures in the final document
def ConvertRtfToDocx(rootDir, file):
    word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    wdFormatDocumentDefault = 16
    wdHeaderFooterPrimary = 1
    doc = word.Documents.Open(rootDir + "\\" + file)
    for pic in doc.InlineShapes:
        pic.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = True
    for hPic in doc.sections(1).headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InlineShapes:
        hPic.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = True
    doc.SaveAs(str(rootDir + "\\refman.docx"), FileFormat=wdFormatDocumentDefault)
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()
```

As rtf can't have embedded images, this also takes any images from RTF and embeds them into the resulting word docx, so there are no external image reference dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

*I had a similar issue like above so I thought I would post an alternative way to solve the problem:*

You can use the following to save files like .rtf (or other) to any format you are able to save/open within the Word application (such as '.docx', '.rtf', '.doc', '.vcf', '.txt', '.odt' etc. )

For that just change the ending from '.doc' in **new_file_abs** to '.docx' or other!

**You need to have Word installed.**

(Optionally I attached how to convert to .pdf)

You need to pip install:

```
pip install pywin32
pip install docx2pdf (optional if you need to have pdf)
```

**Convert .rtf -> .doc / or any other Word-Format.**

```
from glob import glob
import re
import os
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import constants


def change_word_format(file_path):
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(file_path)
    doc.Activate()

    # Rename path with .doc
    new_file_abs = os.path.abspath(file_path)
    new_file_abs = re.sub(r'\.\w+$', '.doc', new_file_abs)

    # Save and Close
    word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(
        new_file_abs, FileFormat=constants.wdFormatDocument
    )
    doc.Close(False)
```

**Optional if PDF is needed .docx -> .pdf**

```
from docx2pdf import convert

def docx_to_pdf(ori_file, new_file):
     convert(ori_file, new_file)
```

Comment: This has all the images embedded in the final word document as well?

Comment: @is677 Yes it does.

Comment: Do you know why you have to convert it do .doc and then .docx?

Comment: I just noticed that you actually you don't have to do this extra step, you can also just save it to .docx straight away

Comment: I updated the code, should be clear now