# how to convert docx file into rtf file using python Is there is any module to do this?

Tags: python

hi everyone I'm trying to convert docx file into rtf file with python I've done lots of googling but can't found any answer I want

```
input = test.docx
output = test.rtf
```

Comment: does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65724761/6557716

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `docx` module and install `docx` module with this instruction : `pip install python-docx`. Check the code.

```
from docx import Document

f = open('test.docx', 'rb')
document = Document(f)

document.save('test.rtf')
```

Comment: I have looked into the file that is generated, this is just a .docx file with the file extension of rtf

Answer (score -1):

https://pypi.org/project/pyandoc/
this may help

Let’s start with a Markdown document:

```
doc = pandoc.Document()
doc.markdown = '''
# I am an H1 Tag

* bullet point
* more points
* point with [link](http://kennethreitz.com)!
```

Now let’s convert that into a ReST document:

```
>>> print doc.rst

I am an H1 Tag
==============


-  bullet point
-  more points
-  point with `link <http://kennethreitz.com>`_!
```

edit: read the docs

Comment: I've used this module but its gives pandoc have not attribute Document